# (How) can I execute a C# code on a Dynamics CRM server without a plug-in?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

Updating a few records in the database is survivable but not if I need to change, say, 100 of them. I really dislike import/export of data using the XML/Excel technique for a range of reasons. Then I realized that I **could** do that from within a plugin. (NB I'm not arguing it's wise nor recommendable, just doable.)

Of course, I don't need to tell anybody how much trouble such an approach can cause. That got me thinking.

1. Is there a way to execute C# code "on demand"? You'd open a window, type in the code (like one did in CRM4 with JS) and then execute it **once**.
2. If creating a plugin is the only way, can I define my own message? I'd add a `Konrad` message both pre/post-state and (in most cases) do nothing upon it being called.
3. If that isn't feasible, is it wise to add my own general entity? I'd call it `Viltersten`, both polishing my ego and having a hidden, unused entity to execute the code when needed.
4. Any other ways?

Is this a (lazy) mad man question or does anybody else have the same kind of thoughts? I always feel like I'm loosing my touch with data if I can't micromanage it.

Comment: It sounds like a custom workflow assembly, configured to run on demand might be the solution to your problem...

Comment: I think 3) is your best bet here

Comment: @GregOwens You don't mean that atrocity where one need to painfully pull the "steps" onto the graphical designer, right? You are referring to a real work flow coded in C# under WWF, I assume. Aren't those hard/nearly impossible to make them work in the on-line version?

Comment: @glosrob I was afraid that someone would say so. It's a nasty hack and an ugly workaround, in my not so humble opinion. But if it's the best (only?) way to go, what else can I do, right?

Comment: yup, pretty much agree. But then working with CRM is an exercise in compromise so I'm sure there are dirtier hacks around :)

Comment: @KonradViltersten You didn't state CRM Online as a requirement ;) In ignorance of that pre-requisite, custom workflow assemblies are the expected way to "execute (managed) code...on demand"

Comment: @GregOwens Darn, I keep forgetting that those inferior humans aren't good at mind-reading... Sorry, I should've mentioned that...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Can be done via JavaScript and the SOAP services.
2. Not that I'm aware of
3. This is a fine idea to have a plugin based on your entity.  Then whenever you want your plugin to execute, either add another record or update a record within your Viltersten entity.
4. You could also write a console application or a windows service that
   could execute on an automated schedule.